# JavaDoc в JAR из Android module

Tags: java, android, jar

В проекте есть Android Module хочу сделать JAR вместе с JavaDoc.
Получаю JAR таким способом. В gradle модуля прописываю код и в терминале вызываю gradlew makejar. Получаю на выходе JAR файл, но он почему-то без JavaDoc, хотя для каждого метода он прописан. Как сделать JAR в Android Studio чтобы в нем был JavaDoc?

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/lib-' +     "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}" + '.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'lib-' + "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}" + '.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

Comment: Proguard'ом пользуетесь?

Comment: в проекте или модуле?

Comment: для генерации `classes.jar`, который вы переименовываете в `avoauth2`.

Comment: В двух gradle закомментировал, но результат все тот же. Или быть может это где-то в другом месте указывается?
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Для начала объясните что вы понимаете под "JAR вместе с JavaDoc"? И расскажите ещё заодно за чем это вам надо? Сдаётся мне вы хотите одно, а сделать пытаетесь несколько иное. В вашем коде я не вижу ни намека на генерацию жавадоков. У вас просто копирование jar файла с переименованием.

Comment: библиотека jar, и когда я загружу её в другой проект хочу посмотреть JavaDoc. Если говорить проще, у меня сорцы выглядят так, http://joxi.ru/BA001npFBx7n4A и я хочу чтобы они примерно также выглядели у другого разработчика когда он откроет класс из моей jar библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопервых вы не совсем верно создаёте jar файл. Лучше делать так:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
    task.exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    artifact task
}
```

Теперь что бы создать jar библиотеку надо выполнить команду `./gradlew jarRelease`

Теперь что касается включения жавадоков, если вы хотите что бы разработчик использующий вашу либу мог открыть ваши классы и видеть их оригинальное содержимое и JavaDoc комментарии, то вам нужно включить в библиотеку исходники:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir, android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    task.exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    artifact task
}
```

По идее этого достаточно, если же вы хотите добавить в библиотек именно JavaDoc, то есть html странички с описаниями ваших классов и методов, то вам нужно дописать ещё немного:

```
afterEvaluate {
    javadoc.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.classpath.files
    })
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'

    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options {
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    }
    failOnError false
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile, javadoc
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir, android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs, javadoc.destinationDir
    task.exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    artifact task
}
```

Но пихать всё в один jar не лучший вариант. Лучше сделать отдельные jar: с кодом, с исходниками и с жавадоками. А затем распространять их через мавен. Для того что бы опебликовать всё это в локальном мавен репозитории (`~/.m2`) надо добавить в build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    // оставляем этот раздел как у вас уже есть
}

dependencies {
    // ваши зависимости
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

afterEvaluate {
    javadoc.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.classpath.files
    })
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'

    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options {
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    }
    failOnError false
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar, javadocJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar

            android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
                def name = variant.buildType.name
                if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
                    return; // Skip debug builds.
                }
                def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
                task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
                task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
                task.exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
                artifact task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Версию и группу я обычно указываю в gradle.properties файле:

```
group=net.{your name}.{lib name or group name}
version=1.2.3
```

Всё, запускаем `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` и по окончании выполнения в папке `~/.m2` увидим ваш пакет.

Теперь вы можете использовать вашу библиотеку в других ваших проектах добавив в build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.{your name}.{lib name or group name}:{lib name}:{lib version}'
}
```

PS: а вы кстати уверены что вам нужно создавать jar а не aar библиотеку? Если у вас в библеотеке есть ресурсы (всё что в папке res), то они на сколько я помню не попадут в jar ибо у андройда свой формат ресурсов и распространяются они вроде только в aar библиотеках. Но в этом я не уверен, я публиковал только библиотеку без ресурсов.

Comment: А можешь ещё подсказать как переименовать генерируемую библиотеку, а то генерируется просто с названием пакета, а хотелось бы чтобы с номером билда. В коде который я привел такое есть.

Comment: И ещё вопрос, как сделать так чтобы в другом проекте автоматом подгружались все необходимые зависимости(которые у меня в dependencies).

Comment: Если вы указали версию в `build.gradle` или `gradle.properties` то она должна появиться и в названии файлов либ. По поводу зависимостей - если они подключены через `compile 'package:name:version'`, то они должны подгружаться сами, если вы это насильно не отключите.